# What is this character: ⿲舌⿳十⿴囗⿱龹贝⿱一八乚?

Tags: character-identification

This is obviously a newly invented character designed by someone with a message. What the message is, or what the point of the character is completely escapes me though.

[image]

I believe it's IDS is: ⿲舌⿳十⿴囗⿱龹贝⿱一八乚

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a [polysyllabic invented "character"](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3330), part of the online language of Chinese netizens (网语). It is a graphical representation of what one could call a "modern idiom": **贵圈真乱**, *guì quān zhēn luàn*, roughly meaning "[Your social circle is a mess](https://www.zhihu.com/question/22475348)".

The phrase was popularised on BiliBili, although its roots apparently date back to the mid 2000s. Baidu [has an entry](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%B4%B5%E5%9C%88%E7%9C%9F%E4%B9%B1/7116462) on the term. The use of 贵 as a sarcastic honorific is very much in vogue in Chinese netspeak.

The "mess" referred to can cover all manner of 'disapproved' conduct, although the general tone is not necessarily vitriolic.

Comment: I guess that's why 贵 is not really represented in the character.

Comment: @user3306356 yep so 圈真乱 is what it actually is combined with. But 贵圈真乱 is the phrase it refers.

Comment: 贝 part is the representation of 贵。